# Matplotlib: PolyCollection with variable alpha values

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create, with matplotlib and Python, a PolyCollection where each polygon has the same face color but its own alpha value. Based on the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.EllipseCollection.set_alpha), set_alpha() should accept array-like values. Still, when I try it I get:

> TypeError: alpha must be a float or None

This should be a minimal working example returning said error message:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollections

verts = np.array([
   [[ 0, 0 ],
    [ 1, 0 ],
    [ 1, 1 ],
    [ 0, 1 ]],

   [[ 1, 0 ],
    [ 2, 0 ],
    [ 2, 1 ],
    [ 1, 1 ]]])

alpha_vals = np.array([0.1, 0.8])

mesh = PolyCollection(verts)
mesh.set_alpha(alpha_vals)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_collection(mesh)
fig.savefig('polytest.png')
```

I'm working with Python 3.8.8 and matplotlib 3.3.4.

I don't understand whether I am misinterpreting the docs, or if there is some other issue in my code preventing alpha values to be specified for each polygon. Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature was added in `matplotlib` version `3.4.0` and was not mentioned on the documentation release notes, but was mentioned on the github release notes.

You can see the [release notes](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/releases/tag/v3.4.0) for this version and scroll down to the 3rd bulletpoint of "Colors and colormaps" and it's the second nested bullet point there. Alternatively search the page for `alpha` with `ctrl+f`

I checked your code with the most recent version of `matplotlib v3.5.2` and it works as you would expect (note that I also had to update the limits on the x/y axes).

[image]

[image]